# Swift: Custom UITableViewCell out of View not shrinking

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a UITableViewCell custom cell that expands and contracts in height with the press of a button. If I reset the table when the cell is in view the cell contracts (to the correct height) but if I reset the cell when it is out of view then the cell does not contract. I cannot find anything about out of view control of custom cells.
I am using the height to control the expansion of the cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

  if indexPath.row == 0 {  
    if expandedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
      bMExpandedCell.expanded = true
    } else {
      bMExpandedCell.expanded = false
    }

    return expandedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) ? 207 : 88

  } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
    if expandedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
      painExpandedCell.expanded = true
    } else {
      painExpandedCell.expanded = false
    }

    return expandedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) ? 346 : 88

  } else if indexPath.row == 20 {
    let height = CGFloat(136.0)
    return height

  } else  {
    let cellHeight = CGFloat(88.0)
    return cellHeight
  }
}
```

In the custom cell a button is pressed that is activated via a Delegate. It works in all cases except when the cell is out of scope (i.e. reset at the end of the table in row 20) and the cells that are in question are in cell 0 and 1.

```
func painCellTapped(cell: PainTableViewCell) {

 if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
   if expandedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
     expandedIndexPaths.removeAtIndex(expandedIndexPaths.indexOf(indexPath)!)
   } else {
     expandedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
   }
   //    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
   tableView.beginUpdates()
   tableView.endUpdates()
 }
}
```

Row 0 and 1 when loaded

[image: TableView as first loaded]

Row 0 expanded

[image: Row 0 expanded]

Row 21 is the save cell that resets the table. This should shrink the cell.
Reset works when the cell 0 is on screen (pull to refresh).

Comment: Please update with screen shot and demo code through dropbox or drive, so anyone can look into it and provide you solution.

Comment: I will do later today thank you.